# Call datetime.now() each time i run this program

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using beautifulsoup to scrape a website and I would like to compare the scraped date to the date received from a call to datetime.date.today()

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import datetime, urllib2, re

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
url = ('http://phoenix.backpage.com/SportsEquipForSale/')
myUrl = opener.open(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(myUrl)
outfile = open('C:/Projects/Web Scraping Practice/datetime.txt', 'w')
date = soup.find("div", {"class" : "date"})        #scraped date
date = re.sub('[.]', '', date.contents[0]).strip() 
outfile.write(datetime.date.today().strftime('%a %b %w')+ '\n'+ date)
```

Right now the code is just supposed to dump the current date(reformatted) and the scraped date into a file.
The problem I'm having is that datetime.date.today() is only evaluated once so each time i run this program datetime.date.today() is only correct the first day i run the program each day after i receive the cached date
I apologize in advance if this is poorly formatted I'm relatively new to programming.

Comment: `datetime.date.today()` already *is* evaluated every time you run this program, not just the first time. Set your clock to 2015 and run it again, and it will write a 2015 date into the outfile. So… what is the _actual_ problem that you thought this was the cause of?

Comment: after changing the clock i realized i was giving the day of the week (%w) not the day of the month(%d) is there a way to display the day of the month without the leading zero?

Comment: datetime.date.today().strftime('%a %b %d').replace(' 0', ' ') gives the output i needed

Comment: Just about every platform you care about has extensions to `strftime` to print days without leading zeros. Unfortunately, they're all different. In particular: `%#d` on Windows, `%e` on any SUS-compatible Unix-like, `%-d` and `%_d` on any glibc-based on newer-BSD-basde Unix-like. Sadly, hacks like yours are the only way to actually do it portably…

Comment: thanks for the help I'll comeback and upvote once i get some rep.

Answer (score 4):

Your code already *is* calling `datetime.now()` each time it's run.

Apparently what you were confused by was that you were using `strftime('%a %b %w')` on the date, and today looks just like next Wednesday with that format. As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) explain:

- `%a` is the short weekday name.
- `%b` is the short month name.
- `%w` is the weekday number (0 for Sunday to 6 for Saturday).

So, 10 July 2013 is "Wed Jul 3", and 17 July 2013 is also "Wed Jul 3".

---

Apparently you were looking for a way to get the day of the *month*, not the day of the *week*, but without the leading 0.

Unfortunately, there is no portable way to do this directly. The original C `strftime` didn't have it, so that's what went into the C89 standard, and that's what Python copied.

---

If you only want to get this running on your machine, rather than portably: The way CPython actually implements `strftime` is to just call your platform's C function, which probably *does* have a way to get the day without a leading 0.

- [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html) gives `%e`. This means it works on every up-to-date Unix (including Mac) and most Unix-likes (including linux)—but not Windows.
- [glibc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) added, and BSD copied, flag characters to control padding, so you can use `%_d` or `%-d` (depending on whether you want a space or nothing). This means it works on every up-to-date BSD Unix (including Mac) and every glibc-based system (including linux)—but again not Windows.
- [MSVCRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) adds different flag characters, so you can use `%#d`. This means it works on Windows (and a few other platforms that copied it; I think Symbian?)—but not anything else.

Of course if you're using Jython, IronPython, or PyPy, it probably depends on some feature in the underlying Java, .NET, or Python runtime, rather than the C API.

---

If you want this to be portable, you either can't use `strftime`, or you have to post-process it.

You already figured this out for yourself, in a comment:

```
datetime.date.today().strftime('%a %b %d').replace(' 0', ' ')
```

Unless the month name in some locale can start with a 0 (which seems very unlikely), this is obviously safe and effective. But it's a little hacky, so you might want to add a comment.